# Website zoomed by default by Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, frontend

I'm struggling to understand why my website is rendered as zoomed with Chrome (OsX and Linux). I'm able to reproduce the issue only if I visit in incognito mode.
This is the website: https://botsociety.io
Screenshot of the incognito homepage:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LW7BM.png)
Screenshot of how it's supposed to look not zoomed:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7blyM.png)
This weird thing happens even if:

- I deactivate JS execution (so it's not our JS)
- I remove the meta viewport attribute or change it

The issue seems to happen only with Chrome as Safari does not have this issue

Any idea?

Thanks,

Vittorio

Comment: Well, how did you get the not zoomed screenshot?

Comment: Looks fine to me

Comment: @JoshLee: I've reset manually the zoom to default (cmd+0 on Osx)

Comment: @epascarello Are you using Chrome on OsX/Linux? Which version? Thanks!

Comment: latest on osx...